# Django redirect to a link crossing views

Tags: django

The situation is like this.
When an anonymous user visits a secret view, I used the @login_required decorator which can redirect the user to login view and then back to the secret view after successful login. However, I provided a link to the signup view, in case the user doesn't have an account. After the new account is created, it will be redirected back to the login view and asked for initial login.

The problem is the `@login_required` decorator is not going to work in the new login view. How can I redirect the user to the secret view after firstly clicking a link in the first shown login view then submitting the signup form?

Some points to be clear:
I have set a default `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` for going to the login page directly, so I don't want to change it this way.
Successful signup will redirect to login.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `@login_required` decorator in login_view in this scenario, if you add this decorator to a login view then only authenticated users will be able to access the login page, and obviously that not how the login page should be.

So add this in your login_view

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def login_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        url = reverse('home') #change this to your home url name
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

**or** In case if you are using default auth_view then you can pass `'redirect_authenticated_user': True` as a keyword argument to the auth_views from the URLs which will redirect the user to [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.login, {'redirect_authenticated_user': True}, name='login'),
]
```

This will prevent the authenticated users from accessing the login page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I guess I am not clear enough in my question. So there is two way in the process which are 1. visit secret page -> auto-redirect to the login page -> user login successfully -> auto-redirect to the secret view. 2. visit secret page -> auto-redirect to the login page -> user click signup link in login page and then go to the signup page -> user signup successfully -> auto redirect to login view -> user login successfully -> redirect to the secret page. The first way goes well simply using a `@login_required` on the secret view.

Comment: However, in the second way, when you click the signup link, the `?next=/secret-page/` goes away from the url.

Comment: And it will not go back after you signup successfully and then being auto redirect to the login page. The problem is how do you redirect this dynamically. Because normally if a user clicks the login link from other places, it will redirect to the home page. I just want to listen to this specific process in the second way.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a temporary solution. However, it is not elegant and has many duplicate codes.
Since I didn't clearly describe the problem in my first post, I am gonna describe it again with an actual example. Consider a simple website with three main pages, a home page, and an article page, and an introduction page. On the introduction page, there is a link to the article. And it also has a login form page and a signup form page using Django default forms, which can be visited by the links on the home page. I want users to login before visiting the article page. I also include a signup page link inside the login page, so if a user doesn't have an account, he will click the link and fill the CustomUserCreationForm. I set some logic with the form validation:

```
def signup(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('app:custom_login')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)
```

So, a successful signup will redirect the user to custom_login view.
The custom_login view is like this

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
```

urls.py is like this

```
...
    path('signup/', view.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', view.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='custom_login'),
    path('article/', view.article, name='article'),
...
```

To do the redirect after signup, I first copy and paste the register_page view and change the form valid redirect url

```
def signup_article(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('app:article')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)
```

then create a url path for this view

```
    path('signup_article/', view.signup_article, name='signup_article'),
```

then create a new template `login_article.html` copy everything from the original login template and change the signup link in the new template from

```
{% url 'signup' %}
```

to

```
{% url 'signup_article' %}
```

then create a url path for the new template

```
...
    path(
        'login_article/',
        view.CustomLoginView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/login_article.html'
        ),
        name='custom_login_article'
    ),
...
```

```
...
<a href="{% url 'app:signup_article' %}">Don't have an account?</a>
...
```

now use the @login_required decorator for the article view, for users who have an account, this is a shortcut. I specified the login_url to let the decorator to handle the rest of logic.

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login-article/')
def article(request):
    context = 'some context'
    return(render, 'article.html', context)
```

The last thing is to click the link of the article on the introduction page, which is

```
{% url 'app:article' %}
```

It is working right now, but as you can see, there are a lot of steps here, also many duplicate codes. If I have multiple things that need to redirect like this, it would be horrowble. Any better solutions?